# Add bold class to parent which contains new messages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a UL-list where data-total is "Total New Messages":

```
<ul>
    <li data-total="0">Node 1</li>
    <li data-total="4">Node 2</li>
    <li data-total="0">Node 3
        <ul>
            <li data-total="0">sub node 1</li>
            <li data-total="0">sub node 2
                <ul>
                    <li data-total="0">test node 1</li>
                    <li data-total="2">test node 2</li>
                    <li data-total="7">test node 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-total="0">Node 4</li>
</ul>
```

How to add class "new_messages" to all parents if childs have unreaded messages?

Example output:

```
<ul>
    <li data-total="0">Node 1</li>
    <li data-total="4" class="new_messages">Node 2</li>
    <li data-total="0" class="new_messages">Node 3 <!-- childs have new messages -->
        <ul>
            <li data-total="0">sub node 1</li>
            <li data-total="0" class="new_messages">sub node 2 <!-- childs have new messages -->
                <ul>
                    <li data-total="0">test node 1</li>
                    <li data-total="2" class="new_messages">test node 2</li>
                    <li data-total="7" class="new_messages">test node 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-total="0">Node 4</li>
</ul>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should iterate all the `li` *DOM* elements.

You can do this using `Array.from` method in combination with `forEach` by passing a *callback* function which is applied for every item.

Then check if `data_total` is greater than 0 and if it's true just set `className` property for *current* item.

Also, I created a function called *checkIfChildsHaveMessages* which checks if a element has children and if contains at least one which has `new messages`.

```js
function checkIfChildsHaveMessages(item){
  let childrens = item.querySelectorAll('ul li');
  if(childrens.length == 0)
    return item.getAttribute('data-total') > 0;
  return Array.from(childrens).some(ch => ch.getAttribute('data-total') > 0);
}

let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
Array.from(li).forEach(function(item){
  data_total = item.getAttribute('data-total');
  let childsHaveMessages = checkIfChildsHaveMessages(item);
  if(data_total > 0 || childsHaveMessages)
    item.className = "new_messages";
});
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li data-total="0">Node 1</li>
    <li data-total="4">Node 2</li>
    <li data-total="0">Node 3
        <ul>
            <li data-total="0">sub node 1</li>
            <li data-total="0">sub node 2
                <ul>
                    <li data-total="0">test node 1</li>
                    <li data-total="2">test node 2</li>
                    <li data-total="7">test node 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-total="0">Node 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "Node 3" and "sub node 2" need to add class "new_messages" too

Answer (score 0):

For example would work:
`$('li[data-total="0"]').addClass('new_messages');`

If you just want to add a CSS style, you don't need a class but can just use the CSS attribute selector:

```
li[data-total="0"] { 
    background : red;
}
```

```js
$('li[data-total="0"]')
  .addClass('new_messages')
  .parents('li')
    .addClass('new_messages');
```

```css
.new_messages {
background : rgba(255,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-total="0">Node 1</li>
    <li data-total="4">Node 2</li>
    <li data-total="1">Node 3
        <ul>
            <li data-total="1">sub node 1</li>
            <li data-total="2">sub node 2
                <ul>
                    <li data-total="0">test node 1</li>
                    <li data-total="2">test node 2</li>
                    <li data-total="7">test node 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-total="0">Node 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "Node 3" possible with data-total="0" but with class "new_messages" (childs have unreaded messages)

Comment: So if you want to add the class to all the parent LIs as well you can use the https://api.jquery.com/parents/ selector

Answer (score -1):

Using plain Javascript:

```js
// Get all li elements
let list_items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// Loop through all li items
for (let element of list_items) {

  // Check if it has child nodes, etc, add class if it does
  if (element.childElementCount > 0 || element.dataset.total > 0) {
    element.classList.add('new_messages')
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that's the case. The list could still contain _old_ messages, even if there are no _new_ ones.

Comment: Yes, the original question was quite vague here, but it would seem this can't be done in pure CSS for that reason

Comment: Well, he specifically asked how to add a class. Not how to apply a CSS style. It can be done in pure CSS though with `li[data-total="0"] { ... }`

Comment: Yes, I misread the question and have already edited my answer to match. That said, the `li[data-total="0"] { ... }` call also wouldn't work, as he has an element with no child nodes and a `data-total="4"` attribute too